# Webscraping content from a webpage not using selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to this world of webscraping and its libraries. I wanted to extract certain information from a website, but cannot find the text that I am looking for. This is the website: "https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/screen/notification/486901".

I want to extract information like Product, Product category, reference, subject etc from the website and put it into a dataframe.

The approach that I took was to use the requests and Beatifulsoup library to extract text as suggested in many articles. This is the code that I am using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/screen/notification/486901'
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')

text = soup.find_all(text=True)
```

But when I type text to find out what is inside it, I get something like this:

```
text

['\n',
'doctype html',
'\n',
'\n',
'\n',
'\n',
'RASFF WINDOW',
'\n',
'\n',
'\n',
'\n',
' FOR OPEN ID IMPLEMENTATION\n\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="/rasff- 
window/assets/jsrsasign-all-min.js"></script>\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="/rasff- 
window/assets/oidc-client.min.js"></script>\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="/rasff-
.
.]
```

When I use the inspect element I see there is the information I want present in the page but not getting displayed in my text. Also if you check the information is not inside any dynamic javascript, but somehow it is not getting extracted as text.

What should I do in this case, I need to extract information from similar pages(1000's) that's why I was thinking of not using selenium to do the work. Any suggestions or reading is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded from external source, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can use `requests` module to get data from their API:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


api_url = "https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/backend/public/notification/view/id/486901/"
data = requests.get(api_url).json()

#uncomment this to print all returned data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data:
print(data["reference"])
print(data["subject"])

# or create a df
#df = pd.json_normalize(data)
#print(df)
```

Prints:

```
2021.3617
Salmonella in kipfilet
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works really well, also I learned about this external source data. Just a question, is this the fastest way to extract information from such pages, or are there any particular libraries that I can look into? As I said i would need to extract information from 1000's of similar links.

Comment: @Dawn.Sahil `requests` is definitely faster than using `selenium` - if you want to get 1000s links, look at multiprocessing, threading or using asyncio.

Comment: Apologies if I have misunderstood something but the link that you are using is different from the link I pasted, is there a specific way to get to the link you mentioned. Because if I try to use the same code with the link I posted it does not seem to work.

Comment: @Dawn.Sahil Yes, the original page doesn't contain the data, only JavaScript that runs and load the data from the API URL. To get API URL, you can look at Firefox Developer Tools->Network Tab (or in Chrome). There are all requests the page is doing, one of those requests is this URL.